# Arguments passed to C program change when using the asterisk symbol

Tags: c

I have a simple C program where I want to print the names of all files with some extension. I would provide a path and extension as parameters to the program.

I decided to make a simple main to check my idea.

When I run my program with command `./main *.txt`, and if there are no `.txt` files in that directory, my program will output just *.txt. And where there are two files, for example, file1.txt and file2.txt output will be `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Also, a number of program arguments is changed too.

Here is my program

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Missing file arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%d\n", argc);

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain to me why is this happening, and what would be the correct approach to do this?

Comment: ...and what is happening?

Comment: I am using linux mint 19.

Comment: It's not clear what output you expected. Please provide expected result and what you think is wrong.

Comment: @Gerhardh
I was expecting same result, ```*.txt``` in both running, but now I understand it is because of the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're on Linux, where expansion of special characters such as `*` is done by the *shell*. That means that if you execute your program as e.g.

```
> ./myprog *.txt
```

it is the *shell* which expands `*.txt` into "all files in the current directory which end with `.txt`" and passes *that* as command-line arguments to your program. If you want your actual program to get hold of the unexpanded string `*.txt`, you have to escape/quote it somehow, like this:

```
> ./myprog '*.txt'
```

or

```
> ./myprog \*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it is clear to me why that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't check anything in the file system, but prints the arguments it was given at the command line.

`argv` is the array of the command line arguments - that why when you pass `*.txt` it just prints `*.txt`

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question.